# How to import value in curly braces using format() string function in sed command

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I have a python script in which using sed command and I want to import the value through `format()` function.
my problem is:

> hello.txt:--- foo is an operating system.

```
x="Linux"

print(subprocess.getoutput('sed -i "s/foo/{0}/g" hello.txt'.format(x)))
```

I want to get the output:

> Linux is an operating system.

Comment: Hi! Could you describe more what is wrong with you current script? What output do you currently see?

Comment: I don't get any error but also don't change in the file. the file is as same.
I want to get changes in this file using above method.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`print(subprocess.getoutput(f'sed -i "s/foo/{x}/g" hello.txt')`

This method uses an f-string.